# Custom JQuery dialog on before unloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload, window.onunload

want to show custom jquery dialog box with Yes , No and Cancel button when user tries to navigate away current page/form or try to close window.

on beforeload event shows default browser dialog confirmation. I dont want to show that dialoge.

Is it possible to prevent the default unload event & show custom dialog ?

Comment: [How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following jquery function instead.

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){
  //Display Dialog here.
});
```